# iAd alternative for ios ad display?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, admob, iad

I have an app, and it currently uses iAd. The problem I have right now is some countries, say Malaysia, is using my app, but iAd does not display ads there, so I get no revenue
only in the US, where the iAds are served.

So my question is, is there any ad network I can use so that I can get a snippet of code    and display it in the app via UIWebView when iAd is not available?
I think there is a way, but I don't know if any ad company does that, does ADMob do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Adsense and a `UIWebView` in some of my apps which has worked very well for me. I'm not sure about Malaysian specifically, but there are tons of hits from various countries outside of the U.S.

What I do is just paste the ad code into a php file (or html or whatever) on my server and load that page into a `UIWebView`. I also implement code to detect when a user taps on the ad which I then redirect the user to Mobile Safari.

Correction, Malaysia is on there as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi WrightsCS, thanks for sharing, but the problem is that, in order to get approved by AdSense...i need to create my own web site, and have content it. yesterday i applied to open one, but got an email saying that i am not approved becuase my webpage is blank

Comment: Make a web page that isn't blank. Thrrow your apps icon and some text or screenshots.

Comment: @WrightsCS What is your fill rate with google? with iad I am at 3% :( are you still using this method or have you found a better method today? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you havn't yet, I would suggest to check out [AdWhirl](http://www.adwhirl.com). They do allow you to add various ad networks.

Comment: Yes, you would need to incorporate their sdk files and app key to your code.

Comment: isn't it shuted down ? http://www.fiercedeveloper.com/story/googles-adwhirl-shutdown-what-happens-next-customers/2013-06-24